# btrfs performance comparison: ssd with compression vs hdd without compression

Tags: hard-disk, btrfs, ssd, compression, nvme

Has anyone done any r/w performance comparisons using btrfs with compression enabled on an M.2 nvme ssd vs uncompressed hdd?

Comment: I'm afraid nobody did test like this and most probably never will . Your question is too specific.

Comment: Its specific but in the answer lies a valid use-case. Anyone who has to deal with large files would benefit having some idea on how it compares so that they can make educated guess about their own setup.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Phoronix has done some benchmarks of BTRFS and compressed BTRFS on both SSDs and HDDs that might give you a general idea of performance compared.

- https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=btrfs_zfs_ssd
- https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=btrfs_compress_2635

Of course, your real results will depend on both the options you set (which compression algorithm you have BTRFS use, and at what level of compression) and your hardware's performance (both disk speed and how quickly compression may be applied), plus other variables (other applications running, what software/firmware is used, etc).

You may want to start by doing small benchmarks of your own using your hardware. Then you can record your results and compare them to find what will work best for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I decided to go with an LVM stripping setup using 6 to 7 HDDs and got good SSD like speed with cheap HDD like capacity. I wish I could upvote your answer as this is what I was looking for at that time.